# I am writing a program based on OS processes in C language and having trouble ending the terminating the program

Tags: c, while-loop, process

My program won't terminate despite reaching the last line, "return 0;" seems to be doing nothing despite breaking from the while loop

Here's the chunk of code.

```
int main(){
    pid_t pid;
    int input;

    printf("Menu: \n 1 -> ls\n 2 -> ps\n 3 -> date\n 0 -> exit program\n");

    char* argv[] = {"", NULL};

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter: ");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0){
            if (input == 0){
                break;
            }
            else if (input == 1){
                execvp(argv[0] = "ls", argv);
            }
            else if (input == 2){
                execvp(argv[0] = "ps", argv);
            }
            else if (input == 3){
                execvp(argv[0] = "date", argv);
            }
            else{
                printf("Wrong Input\n");
            }
        }
        else if (pid > 0){ //non negative value
            while(wait(NULL) != -1);
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
        }
    }
    printf("parent terminating\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to break from the while loop and it seemed to work since printf("parent terminating") was printed. But the program just wouldn't exit.

I'm not sure about my method of having the parent wait for the child either

Comment: You only break from the loop in child, and only when 0 is entered.

Comment: Thanks bro, I had to nest another if-else condition

Comment: `switch(input)` would be a good fit here then use a goto or flag to break out of the loop.  To make your pritnt statement readable you use the fact that C will concatenate consecutive strings "1\n" "2\n" and these strings you have have on multiple lines.  Always check the return value of `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized data.